# In C/C++ Where are Arrays allocated when array dimension is taken from user input

Tags: c++, arrays, c

I know that in C/C++ arrays should be allocated into the stack, as they are static data structures, so if I write:

```
int a[2];
```

the space needed to store 2 integer numbers should be allocated into the stack.

But if we consider the situation where the dimension is, for example, taken from user input, like the following one:

```
int dim;

cout << "Tell me array's dimension: ";    
cin >> dim;

int a[dim];
```

What is happening here? I suppose the array should be allocated into heap, since the compiler has no way to know in advance the amount of integers we need to store, is it correct? Maybe it is similar to what we do when we implement dynamic structure (eg: linked lists) using malloc? Is this handled in all languages pretty much the same way or there are notable cases in which things are done differently?

Comment: c and c++ are very different languages, choose one.

Comment: Standard C++ does not support Variable Length Arrays. Use `std::vector`.

Comment: C++ using `new` and `delete` C using `malloc` `free`

Comment: C:
int *p=malloc(100*sizeof(int));
free(p);

Comment: The array `a` is not “allocated”, it’s placed on the stack. Variable-length arrays on the stack are non-standard, it just so happens that certain compilers support such an extension. If  you compile it with something like `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, the compiler should warn about non-standard stuff.

Comment: @JCHEN — `new int(100)` allocates an object of type `int` and initializes it with the value `100`. To allocate an array with `100` elements use `new int[100]`.

Comment: C++: int *p = new int[100]; delete []p; –

Comment: don't push variable inside [] like b[a] using clear value like:int p[5];if you want special length after some active using new like: int n; cin >>n;int *p = new int[n];

Comment: There is nothing called "C/C++" and this code is invalid in both standard C and standard C++. Please clarify if you are interested in standard C, C with non-standard extensions, standard C++ or C++ with non-standard extensions.

Answer (score 3):

This is still allocated on the stack - now the stack has variable size so the compiler may have to add some extra code to keep track of the stack size - that is perfectly okay.

In C this is standard since C99. In C++ this is a non-standard compiler-specific extension. Compilers that don't support it will raise an error.

> Is this handled in all languages pretty much the same way or there are notable cases in which things are done differently?

Different languages are different. In Python, for example, or Java, or Lua, there is no way to write anything comparable to this declaration; all arrays are heap-allocated.

Answer (score 2):

> I know that in C/C++ arrays should be allocated into the stack

Neither C nor C++ define "the stack"

> as they are static data structures

no, you can have array objects in dynamic or automatic storage too.

> the space needed to store 2 integer numbers should be allocated into the stack.

Not necessarily. An implementation might choose to hold those `int`s in registers if their address is never observed.

Comment: “Static” is an English word meaning “unchanging.” The question’s description of arrays as “static data structures” uses “static” in that ordinary English sense, not in the C standard’s technical sense of static storage duration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil yes, it's nonsensical to say that fixed size things "should be on the stack"

Answer (score 1):

This is called VLA (variable length array). It exists in C from C99 on.

However in standard C++ this doesn't exist, but some C++ compilers (e.g gcc) have it as an extension.

```
int dim;
cin >> dim;
int a[dim];   // VLA (variable length array)
```

In that case the memory is usually allocated on the stack.
VLAs are freed automatically upon function exit, there is no need to take any action to free them.

---

**General advice**

Don't abuse VLAs as the storage space for VLAs is usually limited (because usually they are allocated on the stack) and allocating more memory than available, usually doesn't end well.